# Instagram iOS hooks with non-square images

Tags: ios, instagram

Now that the Instagram app can handle and post non-square images from within that app, I was hoping that I could send non-square images to the Instagram app from my app using the same provided iPhone hooks I've been using (https://instagram.com/developer/iphone-hooks/?hl=en). However, it still seems to be cropping my images to square and not giving me the option to expand them to their non-square size (unlike when I load a non-square photo from the library from directly within the Instagram app and it lets me expand it to its non-square original dimensions). Anyone had any luck sending non-square images? I'm hoping there's some tweak that will make it work.

Comment: I'm also looking for this. Did you tested different proportions? It seems that inside Instagram app, it crops a little portrait pictures, so maybe we have to find the right rectangle to crop?

Comment: Whats interesting is that the instagram app itself doesn't seem to allow you to take landscape or portrait images either. Its only images imported from the library which allow this. It seems like this new "feature" is only half baked.

Answer (score 0):

I too was hoping that they would take non-square photos with the update, but you're stuck with the old solution for posting non-square photos.... matte them to square with white.

https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/blob/master/Classes/ShareKit/Sharers/Services/Instagram/SHKInstagram.m

```
- (UIImage *)imageByScalingImage:(UIImage*)image proportionallyToSize:(CGSize)targetSize {

UIImage *sourceImage = image;
UIImage *newImage = nil;

CGSize imageSize = sourceImage.size;
CGFloat width = imageSize.width;
CGFloat height = imageSize.height;

CGFloat targetWidth = targetSize.width;
CGFloat targetHeight = targetSize.height;

CGFloat scaleFactor = 0.0;
CGFloat scaledWidth = targetWidth;
CGFloat scaledHeight = targetHeight;

CGPoint thumbnailPoint = CGPointMake(0.0,0.0);

if (CGSizeEqualToSize(imageSize, targetSize) == NO) {

    CGFloat widthFactor = targetWidth / width;
    CGFloat heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

    if (widthFactor < heightFactor)
        scaleFactor = widthFactor;
    else
        scaleFactor = heightFactor;

    scaledWidth  = width * scaleFactor;
    scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

    // center the image

    if (widthFactor < heightFactor) {
        thumbnailPoint.y = (targetHeight - scaledHeight) * 0.5;
    } else if (widthFactor > heightFactor) {
        thumbnailPoint.x = (targetWidth - scaledWidth) * 0.5;
    }
}


// this is actually the interesting part:

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(targetSize);

[(UIColor*)SHKCONFIG(instagramLetterBoxColor) set];
CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0,0,targetSize.width,targetSize.height));

CGRect thumbnailRect = CGRectZero;
thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
thumbnailRect.size.width  = scaledWidth;
thumbnailRect.size.height = scaledHeight;

[sourceImage drawInRect:thumbnailRect];

newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

if(newImage == nil) NSLog(@"could not scale image");

return newImage ;
```

}

Comment: I suggest reporting a bug, I did ;)